# Script runs in Python but not in Python shell

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-idle

I am a real newbie in C++. I teach High School Tech Apps courses but my principal has given me a programming class, mid year. I am doing ok by staying one step ahead of the class but I have a program turned in by a student that does not work and I can't see what is wrong. If I paste this directly into the Python command line, it works fine. If I open it in IDLE it does not work.
Here is the script:

```
""" For this program to work as planned
use the keys W,A,D, and SPACE
W will draw a circle
A will draw a triangle
D will end the program
and Space will move the turtle """


from turtle import *


#this draws you a red circle
def draw_circle():
    # This function draws a red circle
    color("red")
    width(10)
    penup()
    goto(-200, -200)
    pendown()
    circle(20)



#this draws a green trinangle

def draw_triangle():
    # This function draws a green triangle 
    color("green")
    width(10)
    penup()
    goto(0, -200)
    pendown()
    right(180)
    circle(15, steps =3)

#this moves the turtle

def move_turt():
    penup()
    goto(-200, 100)
    pendown
    #this ends the program

def end():
    bye()


draw_circle()
draw_triangle()

listen()

onkey(move_turt, "space")
onkey(draw_circle, "w")
onkey(draw_triangle, "a")
onkey(end, "d")
```

Comment: When I run your code with IDLE for 3.7.0a2, Win 10, it works as programmed.  (Always drawing in the same position makes it hard to see that it keeps working.)  Python, tkinter, IDLE, and turtle have all had bug fixes since 3.2 and a few thousand improvements overall.  To be fair to developers and readers, you should edit your question to specify that you are using an old version (3.2 according to your comment on cdlane's answer).

Comment: @PamD, if you've been stuck with teaching programming mid-year, you may also be interested in checking out one of StackOverflow's little sister sites, [cseducators.se].

Answer (score 1):

> If I paste this directly into the python command line, it works fine.
>   If I open it in IDLE it does not work.

That's strange, I see the opposite when I *run* it at the command line under `python3`, it falls through the bottom of the code due to a lack of a call to `mainloop()` at the end.  But it works fine under Python's `idle3` as that environment doesn't require a call to `mainloop()`.

However, *pasting* it into the Python interpreter does work as that doesn't terminate the program.

My rework of the code, for what it's worth:

```
"""
For this program to work as planned
use the keys W, A, D, and SPACE
W will draw a circle
A will draw a triangle
D will end the program
and Space will move the turtle
"""

from turtle import *

def draw_circle():
    """ This function draws a red circle """
    color("red")
    width(10)
    penup()
    goto(-200, -200)
    pendown()
    circle(20)

def draw_triangle():
    """ This function draws a green triangle """
    color("green")
    width(10)
    penup()
    goto(0, -200)
    pendown()
    right(180)
    circle(15, steps=3)

def move_turt():
    """ move the turtle """
    penup()
    goto(-200, 100)
    pendown()

def end():
    """ end the program """
    bye()

onkey(move_turt, "space")
onkey(draw_circle, "w")
onkey(draw_triangle, "a")
onkey(end, "d")

listen()
mainloop()
```

Are you working with Python 3 or Python 2?

Comment: I am using Python 3.2. Your code won't work for me in either compiler.